# Ant exec command argument dealing with multiple files

Tags: java, ant, exec, less-unix

I am using ant exec command to implement the less utility to view the source code of a bunch of .java files. (I know that there are other ways to do this like using `concat`)

So the call `ant view` works if I specify only one file:

```
<target name="view">
    <exec executable="less" dir=".">
        <arg value="Main.java"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

But if I change my code to `<arg value="*.java"/>` to view all files, it actually searches for a file named `*.java`.

Apparently I can put a bunch of `arg`'s for each file, but is there a way to do this with one `arg` ?

Comment: Passing `*.java` as an `arg value` works for me and prints out all java source files (ant 1.8.3 - windows/cygwin). What OS/ant version?

Comment: My ant version is 1.9.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `foreach` which requires [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/)

```
<target name="view">
  <foreach target="call-less" param="file">
    <fileset dir="${src}" includes="**/*.java" />
  </foreach>
</target>

<target name="call-less">
    <exec executable="less">
        <arg value="${file}" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

Comment: Does this execute as many `less` processes as files?

Answer (score 3):

The `*` glob is expanded by the shell on Unix-likes, that's why less doesn't do it itself.

Apart from `<exec>` there is `<apply>` which works on a resource collection:

```
<apply executable="less" dir="." parallel="true" relative="true">
  <fileset dir="." includes="*.java"/>
</apply>
```